# group by two variables in R - table

Tags: r, for-loop, aggregate

I have the following code, where i try to count the number of doctor per variable X1 ("type de séjour") and variable X2 ("spécialité"), for each year. The variables of the number of doctor take the value 1 or 0, because there is one doctor per line (it isn't aggregated yet). My data frame looks like this :

```
[x1]                [x2]       [x3 - year 1]      [x2 - year 2]    [x3 - year 3]

hospitalisation    ortho         1                     1               1

hospitalisation    ortho         0                     1               0

hospitalisation    chir          0                     0               1

hospitalisation    chir          0                     1               1

hospitalisation    chir          1                     1               1
```

I cannot find a way to aggregate by two variables as the function aggregate since to not function. I have also tried the following for-loop :

```
for (i in 1:319) {
  aggregate(df1[i,1], by = list(df1$X2), FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

but it does not work (my data frame is called df1).
Can anybody help? I am new to R and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))`.

Comment: i have tried your code, the problem is that it aggregates years, whereas i would have to have one column per year (in order to have the nb of doctors per specialty, per type, for each year)... it does help though

Answer (score 0):

First sum the row values, then `aggregate` by the two variables of interest.

```
doctors <- rowSums(df1[-(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE)
aggregate(doctors ~ X1 + X2, df1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#               X1    X2 doctors
#1 hospitalisation  chir      30
#2 hospitalisation ortho      60
```

---

### Test data

```
set.seed(2022)    # make the results reproducible
X <- matrix(rbinom(20*10, 1, prob = 0.4), ncol = 10)
X1 <- rep("hospitalisation", 20)
X2 <- sort(sample(c("ortho", "chir"), 20, TRUE))
colnames(X) <- paste0("X", 3:12)
df1 <- data.frame(X1, X2, X)
```